# ,Why is TorBirdy not deployed in Tails?

Tags: tails, email, torbirdy

Why is TorBirdy not deployed in Tails?

It is possible to combine Thunderbird and TorBirdy for anonymous and secure email. Instead, Tails ships Claws Mail without any visible Tor specific configuration.

Comment: All of Tails' traffic already runs over Tor, so why would an email client need additional configuration for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is work to be done at various level. See the relevant [blueprint](https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/Return_of_Icedove__63__/).